# I should choose "installed' or "was installed"

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

I don't know I should choose which of two this options.

> We are assuming at this point that you have MAMP(or some environment equivalent) and composer **installed/was installed**
>   at this point.

Comment: Short answer: assuming "Composer" is software, you should say "was installed." Otherwise, you have an incomplete thought that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Active: *Someone* installs *some thing*.

Passive: *Some thing* is installed *by someone*.

> A: I **installed** Composer
>
> P: Composer **was installed**

*However*, *installed* is also an adjective, describing the current state of the program.  So in your sentence *is installed* can also be accurate:

> Yes, Composer **is installed** on the server.

So it's really your choice:

> We assume, at this point, that you have **both** MAMP and Composer installed.
>
> We assume, at this point, that you have MAMP, and Composer **was installed** (or, even better, **has been installed**).

If accurate, you can avoid the ambiguous verbiage as follows:

> At this point, we assume that you **have installed** both MAMP and Composer.

Comment: so Do I choose **installed**  or **was installed**?

Comment: I don't have enough information to understand how these component relate to each other, so I can't answer that question.  Both might be correct.  I hoped my answer addressed the underlying *grammar* so you could make your own decision ... and also, hopefully show you how to write better English so that, in the future, you can avoid these kind of awkward choices.

Comment: @PhamVanDuc please look at the last sentence and see if it is correct for what you want to say.   This sentence is simple and direct, and is therefore easy for the reader to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> We are assuming ... you have MAMP [...] and Composer installed

Resultative HAVE—*HAVE [object] VERB<sup>Pa·Ppl</sup>*—is an established and very common construction meaning that [object] is present or available in a *VERB<sup>Pa·Ppl</sup>*. It's very similar to the ordinary perfect (in fact, it is believed to be the construction from which the perfect developed), but unlike the perfect it doesn't imply that the subject performed the action which brought about the state. For instance:

> We cannot proceed until we have the objectives explicitly defined ... *that is, until the objectives are before us in an explicitly defined state. Somebody has to define the objectives, but that somebody may not be us—perhaps it is our client.*
>
> Now that we have the report drafted we can consider amendments ... *that is, the report has now been drafted and we have a document we can amend. Somebody drafted it, but it wasn't necessarily us—perhaps it was a consultant, or our staff.*

Your sentence thus means "We are assuming that MAMP and Composer have been installed and can be run on your system."

Comment: so Do I choose **installed**  or **was installed**?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc *Installed*, as the first line of the Answer says.

Comment: **installed** in this case is an adjective or a verb?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc Well, a participle is by definition both; but this is more adjective-y than verb-y.

Comment: -y at the end-word mean?

Comment: @PhamVanDuc It's a very old adjectival suffix (e.g. luck-y, happ-y), derived from OE *-ig*. It's no longer very productive, except in semi-joking contexts like this.

Comment: You mean **A participle is by definition both(adjective and verb) ,but It is usually more _adjective_ than _verb_**

Comment: @PhamVanDuc Not quite. "A participle is by definition both an adjective and a verb; but in this instance it acts more like an adjective than like a verb."

Answer (score 0):

You don't say "you have somehing was done".

The right form is "have + something + done" when you want to say that something is done by someone else for you.

So the phrase "was installed" isn't grammatical in the sentence; you should use installed without was/were.